# How to add a name to the probability column I just got?

Tags: python, pandas

I have written the following code to add a probability for the following condition:

```
df2=df.groupby('ACTUAL_START_DATE')['PRACTICE'].value_counts()/df.groupby('ACTUAL_START_DATE')['PRACTICE'].count()
```

After i executed this code, i cant seem to add a name to the probability column I get.

Comment: Is the output a Pandas Series? if so you can simply name it when adding it to a dataframe. df['column_name'] = series

Answer (score 1):

Hope I got the question right.. below line will auto add the column and assign value to it

```
df2['probability']=df.groupby('ACTUAL_START_DATE'['PRACTICE'].value_counts()/df.groupby('ACTUAL_START_DATE')['PRACTICE'].count()
```

Comment: Problem is you cannot pass Series with MultiIndex to DataFrame column here

Comment: hi, @jezrael, , what I understand is , calculate value in 2 columns and assign to some column new column in data frame, , I have not performed exact same calculation but percentage, sum, difference in dates etc in few of my assignments,, and used this syntax ,, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-of-two-columns-in-pandas-dataframe/.... Still, better solutions are always welcome .. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here `df2` is `Series`, if want new column use `rename` with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df.join(df2.rename('new'), on=['ACTUAL_START_DATE','PRACTICE'])
```